# Sum habitat type within region using MapInfo?

Tags: vector, mapinfo, fields-attributes, select-by-attribute

I have two layers; one shows admin regions and the other shows habitats within those regions with columns for specific attributes and the corresponding area in hectares.

I need to work out the total area for each habitat attribute and I'd like to split this by region from the first layer.

Is there a simple way to do this in MapInfo?

Comment: You will need to join the layers/tables using a field that is common to both of them, such as a polygon id, parcel id, ppin, or something similar.

You can then query out, and sum the areas by habitat type, or create a thematic map depicting the different habitat types, and the sums of the areas for each type.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your habitats are regions, too. In that case you might need to split the habitat regions with your admin regions in order to get the exact area within each region.

The good thing is that you can do all this in a single SQL Select statement:

```
Select ADMIN_NAME, Sum(CartesianArea(Overlap(ADMIN.obj, HABITATS.obj), "hectare")) "Summed_Areas_Ha"
From ADMIN, HABITATS
Where ADMIN.obj Intersects HABITATS.obj
Group By ADMIN_NAME
Order By ADMIN_NAME
```

Notice that I calculate the area of the area of the habitats within the individual admin regions and sum these per admin region.

I have used ADMIN as the name of your table with admin regions and ADMIN_NAME as a column holding unique name or ID's of your admin regions.

And I used HABITATS as the name of your table with habitat regions.

Comment: Yep, this has worked with a bit of tweaking, so thanks again Peter. Have a good day!

Comment: @MatG, any tweaks we should mention here for the next person having a similar question?

Comment: Good point.
The only relevant tweak was having to also group by HABITATS, to show the multiple habitat types within an ADMIN region.

Thanks again.